# How should I join to achieve this

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I am in kind of situation where I don't know where to go. I have to write a query such that it is kind of hierarchical.

I will explain you with an example-

Table A

Here we have 3 columns like this

```
  Country      State          City      
  India      Punjab         Amristar     
  India      Punjab         Ludhiana    
  India     Tamil Nadu      Chennai         
  India     Tamil Nadu       Salem  
  India     West Bengal     Kolkata 
  India     West Bengal     Darjeeling
  India     Maharastra      Mumbai                           
  India     Maharastra      Nagpur
```

Table B

Here we have 4 columns like this

```
Country      State          City         Number
  India      Punjab       Amristar         3
  India      Punjab       null             5
  India     Tamil Nadu    Chennai          2    
  India     Tamil Nadu      null           4
  India      null           null           6
```

Now we have to join these two tables on a hierarchical level like -

If the two Country matches, their states matches and their City matches than Number assigned to them

If two Country matches, their states matches and their City doesn't match (or it is null in another table) then we have to assign that Number from Table B whereby joining those two tables city will be null and other two column match

**It is like a hierarchy first we matach till the lowest granuality level, if that matches its ok if not go to one level up and like this.**

If only the two country matches than we have to assign the number where other two columns are null.

My output for the above two will be like this-

```
Country        State          City             Number
  India       Punjab        Amristar              3      
  India       Punjab        Ludhiana              5
  India     Tamil Nadu      Chennai               2
  India     Tamil Nadu       Salem                4
  India     West Bengal     Kolkata               6
  India     West Bengal     Darjeeling            6
  India     Maharastra      Mumbai                6                      
  India     Maharastra      Nagpur                6
```

Now I have  a approch to achieve this also i.e.,

First I  inner join both of them and goal column will be filled like-

```
Country       State          City            Number
  India       Punjab        Amristar           3      
  India       Punjab        Ludhiana           
  India     Tamil Nadu      Chennai            2
  India     Tamil Nadu       Salem                       
  India     West Bengal     Kolkata          
  India     West Bengal     Darjeeling                 
  India     Maharastra      Mumbai                               
  India     Maharastra      Nagpur
```

Now I will join on the basis of Country and State and with condition

that goal should not filled in Table A and City is null in Table B.

Which will give me this-

```
Country       State          City            Number
  India       Punjab        Amristar           3      
  India       Punjab        Ludhiana           5   
  India     Tamil Nadu      Chennai            2
  India     Tamil Nadu       Salem             4           
  India     West Bengal     Kolkata          
  India     West Bengal     Darjeeling                 
  India     Maharastra      Mumbai                               
  India     Maharastra      Nagpur
```

Now I will join on country basis and where goal is empty in table A and state is null in table B

which we be like this-

```
   Country       State          City             Number
      India       Punjab        Amristar           3      
      India       Punjab        Ludhiana           5   
      India     Tamil Nadu      Chennai            2
      India     Tamil Nadu       Salem             4           
      India     West Bengal     Kolkata            6
      India     West Bengal     Darjeeling         6       
      India     Maharastra      Mumbai             6                 
      India     Maharastra      Nagpur             6
```

This is what I want eventually

Now a problem with this approch is it based on update. But here I have to do select.

How to write this in sql. That is my problem.

Please can anyone help me out here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done easily using several `LEFT JOINS` on different criteria:

```
DECLARE @Countries TABLE
(
    [Country] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[State] VARCHAR(16)
   ,[City] VARCHAR(16)
);

INSERT INTO @Countries ([Country], [State], [City])
VALUES ('India', 'Punjab', 'Amristar')
      ,('India', 'Punjab', 'Ludhiana    ')
      ,('India', 'Tamil Nadu', 'Chennai  ')
      ,('India', 'Tamil Nadu', 'Salem  ')
      ,('India', 'West Bengal', 'Kolkata ')
      ,('India', 'West Bengal', 'Darjeeling')
      ,('India', 'Maharastra', 'Mumbai')
      ,('India', 'Maharastra', 'Nagpur');

DECLARE @CountriesCodes TABLE
(
    [Country] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[State] VARCHAR(16)
   ,[City] VARCHAR(16)
   ,[Number] TINYINT
);

INSERT INTO @CountriesCodes ([Country], [State], [City], [Number])
VALUES ('India', 'Punjab', ' Amristar', '3')
    ,('India', 'Punjab', NULL, '5')
    ,('India', 'Tamil Nadu', 'Chennai', '2')
    ,('India', 'Tamil Nadu', NULL, '4')
    ,('India', NULL, NULL, '6');

SELECT C.[Country]
      ,C.[State]
      ,C.[City]
      ,COALESCE(CC1.[Number], CC2.[Number], CC3.[Number]) AS [Number]
FROM @Countries C
LEFT JOIN @CountriesCodes CC1
    ON C.[Country] = CC1.[Country]
    AND C.[State] = CC1.[State]
    AND C.[City] = CC1.[City]
LEFT JOIN @CountriesCodes CC2
    ON C.[Country] = CC2.[Country]
    AND C.[State] = CC2.[State]
    AND CC2.[City] IS NULL
LEFT JOIN @CountriesCodes CC3
    ON C.[Country] = CC3.[Country]
    AND CC3.[State] IS NULL
    AND CC3.[City] IS NULL;
```

[image]

Now, let's say there is additional column `Number` in the first table which you want to update (I guess this is what you want):

```
UPDATE @Countries 
SET [Number] = COALESCE(CC1.[Number], CC2.[Number], CC3.[Number])
FROM @Countries C
LEFT JOIN @CountriesCodes CC1
    ON C.[Country] = CC1.[Country]
    AND C.[State] = CC1.[State]
    AND C.[City] = CC1.[City]
LEFT JOIN @CountriesCodes CC2
    ON C.[Country] = CC2.[Country]
    AND C.[State] = CC2.[State]
    AND CC2.[City] IS NULL
LEFT JOIN @CountriesCodes CC3
    ON C.[Country] = CC3.[Country]
    AND CC3.[State] IS NULL
    AND CC3.[City] IS NULL;
```